# ListInstance provisioning via CAML

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010, is it possible to not overwrite an existing ListInstance (assuming it already exists) when provisioning a list using CAML?  Or is custom code necessary?

Edit: 
This question was unclear on my part.  I should have noted that I am deploying the list instance via a solution using the default vs2010 build/deploy process.  When using this process, the list instance is being removed and re-created when I deploy.  I am trying to prevent it from being re-created each time.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to overwrite an existing List with the [ListInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476062.aspx) element. You can change [EnableVersioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.enableversioning.aspx) and [Hidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.hidden.aspx). You can also add items via Data/Rows/Row. But the original list remains.

From the "[documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)," here is code from Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListInstanceElement:

```
internal override void ElementActivated(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSqlCommand sqlcmdAppendOnly, SPWebApplication webApp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, bool fForce)
{
  bool flag1 = this.FeatureDefinition.Scope == SPFeatureScope.Site;
  bool flag2 = true;
  if (this.RootWebOnly && !web.IsRootWeb)
    flag2 = false;
  if (!flag2)
    return;
  this.EnsureDataProvisioned(this.EnsureListExists(!flag1 ? web : site.RootWeb));
}

internal SPList EnsureListExists(SPWeb web)
{
  SPList spList = web.Lists.GetListByName(this.Title, false);
  if (spList == null)
  {
    // SNIP - list would be created here
  }
  bool flag = false;
  if (this.VersioningEnabled.HasValue && spList.EnableVersioning != this.VersioningEnabled.Value)
  {
    spList.EnableVersioning = this.VersioningEnabled.Value;
    flag = true;
  }
  if (this.Hidden.HasValue && spList.Hidden != this.Hidden.Value)
  {
    spList.Hidden = this.Hidden.Value;
    flag = true;
  }
  if (flag)
    spList.Update();
  return spList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful information.  Not quite what I was looking for, but only because I was unclear with my question.  I have updated it with more info.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying a solution, VS prompts the user if they want to overwrite the existing list instance.  To prevent the list from being overwritten (and this prompt all together), the "[Deployment Conflict Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330922.aspx)" can be changed to "None".  "Deployment Conflict Resolution" can be found in the properties window of the list instance element.